# What happens when a method returns null

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and need to figure out process when a method return null and reference variable.

Here is the code of the method:

```
 public Lot getLot(int lotNumber)

 {

     if((lotNumber >= 1) && (lotNumber < nextLotNumber)) {

     // The number seems to be reasonable.

        Lot selectedLot = lots.get(lotNumber - 1);

      // Include a confidence check to be sure we have the

       // right lot.

         if(selectedLot.getNumber() != lotNumber) {

            System.out.println("Internal error: Lot number " +

                              selectedLot.getNumber() +

                               " was returned instead of " +

                               lotNumber);

            // Don't return an invalid lot.

            selectedLot = null;

           }
            return selectedLot;
        }

  else {

  System.out.println("Lot number: " + lotNumber +

                            " does not exist.");

      return null;
      }
   }
```

What happens when a method returns null and reference variable, while having a class data type?

Please explain in easy words.

Comment: You might end up with a NPE if you are not careful.. :P. Nothing special happens. Returning `null` is like returning reference to any  other instance.

Answer (score 5):

`null` is valid value for any `Object` in `Java`. Since `Lot` is also a `Java` object. `null` is valid.

**But**

If you are not careful you may end up with `NullPointerException`.

Eg:

```
Lot lot=someInstance.getLot(2); // say lot is null
```

Then

```
String something=lot.getThis(); // here is null.getThis()
```

You will end up `NullPointerException` here.

You need to handle with care these cases to avoid `NullPointerException`.

Eg:

```
Lot lot=someInstance.getLot(2);
if(lot!=null){
 String something=lot.getThis();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Null` in java means, that your instance (variable) contains no object. You can use it, but you must not call any method on that object, because If you did so, you'd get a `NullPointerException`.

When `null` is returned from a method, it usually means that the method was not able to create a meaningful result. For example the method, that reads data from database was not able to find the specified object or some error occurred during the method run.

If a method can return null, then you should check the result before further processing like. See the example of raising a sallary of an employee:

```
Employee e = database.getEmployeeById(1);
if (e==null) //this is the check
{
    System.out.println('There is no such employee');
}
else
{
    e.setSallary(e.getSallary() * 1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `null` is a value, your program will compile fine.

But depending in the situation you are using a `null` variable you may end up with `NullPointerException` while running your app.